# Hovering over child but exclude parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a child div inside of a parent div with the same class.  Right now, if you hover over the child div inside the parent, a border is added to both the child and the parent.  I want to make sure that only the div being hovered will get a border applied to it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                            $(".content").hover(function () {
                                $(this).parents().removeClass('divHoverBorder');
                                $(this).siblings().removeClass('divHoverBorder');
                                $(this).addClass("divHoverBorder");
                                $(this).parents().find(".addContentItemDiv").hide();
                                $(this).find(".addContentItemDiv:first").show();

                            }, function () {
                                $(this).removeClass("divHoverBorder");
                                $('.addContentItemDiv').hide();
                            });
                        });

<div class="content" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
    <div class="content" style="width: 500px;  height: 200px;">

</div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle of what I'm referring to:

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbishop2140/tTUaj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is here:

```
<div class="content" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
    <div class="content" style="width: 500px;  height: 200px;">    
</div>
```

Since both divs have the same class, you're effectively putting a hover event on both of them and your JQuery can't distinguish between them.

Since you indicated you have to do it this way, here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").mouseover(function (e) {
        $(this).parents().removeClass('divHoverBorder');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('divHoverBorder');
        $(this).addClass("divHoverBorder");
        $(this).parents().find(".addContentItemDiv").hide();
        $(this).find(".addContentItemDiv:first").show();
        var p = $(this).parent('.content');
        if (p.length) { p.removeClass('divHoverBorder'); e.stopPropagation(); }
    });
    $('.content').mouseout(function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass("divHoverBorder");
        $('.addContentItemDiv').hide();
    });
});
```

Note that you can't use `hover`. Hover uses the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events in JQuery which will prevent firing an event when mouse out from child to parent. We must both remove the parent border (on the case of entering the child) *and* stop propagation to prevent it from reapplying its own border.

Here's an explanation from the JQuery docs about the difference between `mouseenter` and `mouseover`:

> <sup>The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not the Inner element.</sup>

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tTUaj/10/

Comment: Unfortunately they both require the same class.  Is there a way to do this with the same class?

Comment: @user547794 Are you aware you can put more than one class onto a div?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but all of the divs need a common set of functionality.  The way I am assigning that common hover functionality is by using a common class between them.

Comment: @user547794 then just put `<div class="content outer"><div class="content inner">`. Resolve your common functionality on class `content` and your disparate functionality on `outer` and `inner`. Otherwise we will have to write some code that's probably going to be an eyesore going forward.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying, the issue is that this is just a small sample of the number of nested divs that need this functionality.  I need something that can scale to 10+ child divs, and assigning a unique class to each one is going to be a pain.

Comment: Marvelous!  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
 $(".content").hover(function (ev) {
    if ($(ev.currentTarget).parent().hasClass(".content")){
     //this is a child
    } else {
    //this is a parent
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3SVGe/1/

```
$(".cell").hover(function () {
    $(".cell").removeClass("over");
    $(this).addClass("over");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("over");
});
```

Your problem is that when hovering over a subelement, the hover event is triggered on the parent element. This evades the issue.

Alternatively, you could follow a slightly more complex solution, that would allow for hovering on the parent, then the child, then the parent properly. An example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3SVGe/2/